# PLS-00201: identifier 'D.HOLIDAY_DATE' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

here is my code:

```
DECLARE
V_loop                  number(2); -------declare the loop times

begin 

looptimes(V_loop); ------set the forcast times from parameter table
loop 
       IF V_loop > 0 ------forcast 
       THEN 
            IF to_char((sysdate+V_loop-7),'dd/mon/yy') not like To_chat((d.holiday_date),'dd/mon/yy')----------condition that perivous 'day' not holiday
                then
                      insert into local_rm16(tni, lr, frmp, day, hh, volume)
                      SELECT TNI, LR, FRMP, sysdate+v_loop, HH, AVG(VOLUME)
                      FROM V_nem_rm16,DBP_holiday d
                      where to_char(day, 'Day') = to_char(sysdate+V_loop, 'Day')
                      group by day,hh, lr, frmp,tni
                      order by 1;
                 else 
                      exit;
                 end if;
                      V_loop := V_loop -1;
        ELSE 
             exit;
        ENd if;


END loop;
end;
```

i dont know howto declare holiday_date in if conditions, can anyone help me, thx

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use the formatting tools when posting code - this makes your questions much more readable (I've re-formatted your post for you).

Comment: Sorry Frank, bit I was trying to understand why would you need loop at all. Please excuse me if I am in wrong direction. You can use that IF clause condition in where clause while inserting into local_rm16 table..something like- where  to_char((sysdate+5),'dd/mon/yy') not like To_chat((d.holiday_date),'dd/mon/yy') or  to_char((sysdate+6),'dd/mon/yy') not like To_chat((d.holiday_date),'dd/mon/yy')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have written `to_chat` instead of `to_char`:

   `IF to_char((sysdate+V_loop-7),'dd/mon/yy') not like To_chat((d.holiday_date),'dd/mon/yy')`
2. You can't use `d` before you defined it. It's defined in `SELECT` as an alias to `DBP_holiday` table, but you use it earlier in `IF` expression. You should think once again about your code, because you can't do it like this (maybe you should consider using [cursor loop](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm)).